# How to add objects in list view

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to add object into listview.Objects are retriving from calender and retriving data using for each loop so how can i show listview for thet objects.

```
public void getCal()
    {
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                try {
                    String pageToken = null;
                    do {
                      events = client.events().list("primary").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
                      List<Event> items = events.getItems();
                      for (Event event : items) {
                        Log.e("Events",event.getSummary());

                      }
                      pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
                    } while (pageToken != null);
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: what type of data you want to add to listview? a string, an int or a custom created object?

Comment: I'm in a hurry and can't give you the proper answer, but the short answer is: Use an adapter! Just google "android adapter example"

Comment: What adapter are You using?

Comment: hi @Onur A i having list items object and in that object have stribgs data and i want to shows that data in listview

Comment: i know how to use adapter but the problem is my  List<Event> items is implimented in thread.And when i am trying to access "items" values its giving null pointer null pointer exception

Comment: declare a list outside of this method and add the items in it inside this method, and then outside of this method declare an adapter based on the data from your newly created list and bind that adapter to your listview

Comment: i tried lot but error is "only origanal thread that can created view hierarchy can touch its view "

Answer (score 0):

To explain the way to do a listView is beyond the frame here in stackoverflow. You have to do an item layout.xml for a listView with all the components You need to show Your information. Also You have to a Custom Adapter for the list view, if the basic adapters doesen´t fulfill Your needs. But Google is the best teacher, there are a lot of great tutorials for a listView:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php